# Variable as a condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, youtube-api, dom-events, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create simple name generator based on gender first I wrote function which creates gender

```js
function getGender () {
  var genders = ["Female", "Male"]
  var gender = genders[Math.floor(Math.random() * genders.length)]
  return gender
}
```

then I have condition, which should choose to call function based on gender from first function

```js
function getName() {
  if (gender = ["Male"]) {
    getFullName()
  } else {
    getFemaleFullName()
  }
}
```

but result in console.log is still undefined but for other functions when I call them in console.log they write down expected result.

Comment: `gender = ["Male"]` this will always be `true`, and it's an assignation (not a comparison)

Comment: You are assigning an array containing `Male` to `gender`, instead of comparing.

Comment: Typos: `gender = ["Male"]`. First `=` is for assignment, not comparison (use `==` or `===` for that). Second `gender` will be either the string `"Male"` or `"Female"`, but not an Array with those strings.

Comment: Thank you for hints I fixed the condition

function getName (){
    if (getGender () != "Female") {
       return getFullName() }
        else if (getGender () != "Male")
        {return getFemaleFullName()
}}

Answer (score 0):

See comments:

```js
var genders = ["Female", "Male"];
let gender = "";

function getGender () {
  gender = genders[Math.floor(Math.random() * genders.length)];
}

function getName() {
  // === is used to test strict equality
  // and you need to test for the string
  // that was in the array, not an array
  // that contains a string.
  if (gender === "Male") {
    console.log("Male was chosen.");
  } else {
    console.log("Female was chosen.");
  }
}

getName(getGender());
```

Answer (score 0):

it show's undefined because you are not return that function that return value you just calling that function

```
  function getName() {
  if (gender = ["Male"]) {
    getFullName()
  } else {
    getFemaleFullName()
  }
}
```

So console.log not getting any value you can do this

```
 function getName() {
      if (gender = ["Male"]) {
        return getFullName()
      } else {
        return getFemaleFullName()
        }
 }
```

and here is my code for you

```
function getGender() {
    const genders = ['Female', 'Male'];
    const gender = genders[Math.floor(Math.random() * genders.length)];
    return gender;
}

function getFullName() {
    return 'Male';
}

function getFemaleFullName() {
    return 'Female';
}

function getName() {
    if (getGender() == ['Male']) {
        return getFullName();
    } else {
        return getFemaleFullName();
    }
}

console.log(getName());
```